# Can I say this?

Tags: idiomatic-language

If someone asks me:

*What were you doing in Italy?*

Can I answer this:

***I just needed to get a little away from everything.***

Is it perfectly natural?

Comment: A little away sounds a bit odd. Do you mean for a short time or at a short distance?

Comment: ......Distance.